# Pick Value onTap in CupertinoPicker and CupertinoDatePicker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

**onSelectedItemChanged** is working perfectly in CupertinoPicker/CupertinoDatePicker

But I also want to pick value when user clicked the value.

Currently, user must scroll in order to pick the value, and as far as I know **CupertinoPicker/CupertinoDatePicker** doesn't have **onTap, onPressed** functions

How can I solve this issue

[image]

Comment: if you tap on an item, it will lead to scroll to that position, so the onSelectedItemChanged will be invoked.

Comment: @meditat Please, could you clarify your answer? (tapping on an item is not invoking onSelectedItemChanged function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the gesture detection inside `CupertinoPicker/CupertinoDatePicker` is not supported for now. When you trace the code inside `CupertinoPicker`, it leads to use `ListWheelScrollView` at the end and it does not respond to the tap event.

Discussion thread on GitHub:

- [Tapping items is not working in CupertinoPicker](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24089)
- [ListWheelScrollView children do not respond on gesture (onTap) events](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803)

There is a workaround solution by using package [clickable_list_wheel_view](https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view) (fixed height for the child widget, mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38803#issuecomment-762748940))

Comment: It is indeed not working. Me as well tried to figure out a way, but the furthest I got to, was to that github issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    onTap: () => // write what you want to do,
    child: CupertinoPicker(),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using `flutter_portal`.

```
  final ScrollController scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        child: Portal(
          child: CupertinoPicker.builder(
            scrollController: scrollController,
            childCount: itemCount,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return PortalTarget(
                anchor: Aligned(
                  follower: Alignment.center,
                  target: Alignment.center,
                ),
                portalFollower: GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                  onTap: () {
                    scrollController.animateToItem(index,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                        curve: Curves.decelerate);
                  },
                ),
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```